# How to read the information from a txt file into an arraylist

Tags: java

I have a txt document where each line is an independent message. This may include name, date of birth, address, etc. In addition to the address, all other information is in a row. Their order is not fixed. Name and birthday must be available, other information may not be available. If there is no name or birthday, this person should be ignored. Different people use blank lines to distinguish them. I want to read this information and put them in the arraylist, but I have no idea how to write the code.

My initial idea was to use a loop to read the content and store it, and if there was a blank line, start saving another content. But how to implement the code specifically I have no idea.

```java
public class InforProcessor {
    private File recordFile;
    private File instructionFile;
    private File outputFile;
    private InforList inforlist;

    public InforProcessor(String[]s)
    {
        recordFile = new File(s[0]);
        instructionFile = new File(s[1]);
        outputFile = new File(s[2]);
        inforlist =  new InforList();
    }
}
```

This is my existing code, I want to read the contents of the recordFile and write to the arraylist.

Input file is like：

```
    name john
    birthday 11-11-2015
    Address 11 Harry St, montain, TRY

    birthday 12-25-2017
    name peter

    Postcode 2005
    name jane
    birthday 25-19-1998
    Address 25 jeoje St, Sky, FLY

    Postcode 1998
    name geoge
```

The output information or useful information should be:

```
    name john
    birthday 11-11-2015
    Address 11 Harry St, montain, TRY

    birthday 12-25-2017
    name peter

    Postcode 2005
    name jane
    birthday 25-19-1998
    Address 25 jeoje St, Sky, FLY
```

The last information should be delete because it do not have birthday.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Also please take the time to post your code and a proper example of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to read all line from file,and every message splited by empty line.

Second,iterate over the message and check the messag is valid or not,if the message is valid then add the message to list.

```
private static List<String> filterFile(final String input) throws Exception {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File(input), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(lines.size());
    int begin = 0;
    int end = 0;
    for (; end < lines.size(); end++) {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(lines.get(end))) {
            if (isValidInfo(lines, begin, end)) {
                result.addAll(lines.subList(begin, end + 1));
            }
            begin = end + 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

if message has name and birthday,the message is we want.

```
private static boolean isValidInfo(List<String> infos, int begin, int end) {
    int counts = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        String line = infos.get(i);
        if (line.startsWith("name")) {
            counts++;
        }
        if (line.startsWith("birthday")) {
            counts++;
        }
    }

    return counts == 2;
}
```

Comment: This will happily accept a record with two names and without a birthday. It also writes to a file, which wasn't asked for. Finally it's mostly a code dump without much explanation, so the OP probably won't learn much from it. You could greatly improve this answer by explaining the logic. See [answer].